# Selecting All Values where field type is tinyint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am finishing a report where I was asked to include a "ALL" choice so that all the records will show.  The scenario is that the field (Local) contains 0 and 1 only for True and False respectively.  The query I wrote takes forever to load the report when all is selected, is there a better way to do this?  Below is the query I have for show "All"

SELECT        '2' AS Local
UNION
SELECT        local
FROM          tbl

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use an `or`:

```
select *
from tbl
where (Local = @Local or @Local = 2)
```

Or

```
select *
from tbl
where @Local IN (Local, 2)
```